# How to implement a new Dialog error in Android Studo (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, error-handling

So I want to add a dialog message to my app. There already an option for other types of error's. I just want to add  an error for when there's no mobile data and WiFi. It's an older app, so it's taking me a bit more to understand, but here's what I got.

So here is the status code for the errors. Not sure if the codes are random or not (I didn't make this project)

```
public class StatusCodeUtil {

    public static final int AWS_GATEWAY_ERROR = 1;
    public static final int URL_INVALID = 2;
    public static final int INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR = 14;
    public static final int ENDPOINT_INFO_STORAGE_INCOMPLETE = 7;
    public static final int NO_PERMISSION_GET_DEVICE_ID = 8;
    public static final int INVALID_API_FUNCTION = 18;
    public static final int INVALID_HTTP_STATUS_CODE = -1;
    public static final int NO_NETWORK_ERROR = 3; <- This is the status code I want to work
}
```

Here is the Callback for the errors

```
public abstract class  ApiCallBack<T> implements Callback<ApiResponse<T>> {

    private ParabitSDKBeaconApplication application;

    public ApiCallBack(ParabitSDKBeaconApplication application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponse<T>> call, Response<ApiResponse<T>> response) {
        Long roundTripTime = getRoundTripTime(response);

        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            ApiResponse<T> responseBody = response.body();
            onApiResponse(responseBody.getMessage(), response.code(), responseBody.getData());
        } else {
            /**
             * error level 1 (HTTP client or gateway error)
             * */
            String errorBodyJson = getErrorBodyStr(response);
            // can not user ApiResponse<T> to catch the json here
            // will lead to exception: java.lang.AssertionError: illegal type variable reference
            // no good way to solve this (Gson's problem)
            ApiErrorResponse errorBody = GsonUtil.jsonStrToObject(errorBodyJson,
                    new TypeToken<ApiErrorResponse>(){});

            if (errorBody.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("forbidden")) { // x-api-key invalid
                if (getLogControlManager().isLog()) {
                    Log.e(PARABIT_SDK_LOG, "AWS Gateway Error: " + errorBody.getMessage());
                }

                onError(new ApiErrorCodeInfo(AWS_GATEWAY_ERROR, response.code(),
                        errorBody.getMessage()));
            } else if (errorBody.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase(
                    "missing authentication token")) {
                if (getLogControlManager().isLog()) {
                    Log.e(PARABIT_SDK_LOG, "AWS Gateway Error: " + errorBody.getMessage());
                }
                onError(new ApiErrorCodeInfo(INVALID_API_FUNCTION, response.code(),
                        errorBody.getMessage()));
            } else {
                if (getLogControlManager().isLog()) {
                    Log.e(PARABIT_SDK_LOG, "Other Error Response: " + errorBody.getMessage());
                }
                // should never happen for now
                onError(new ApiErrorCodeInfo(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, response.code(),
                        errorBody.getMessage()));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponse<T>> call, Throwable t) {
        /**
         * error level 1 (HTTP client or gateway error)
         * */
        if (t instanceof UnknownHostException) { // host of end point is unknown
            if (getLogControlManager().isLog()) {
                Log.e(PARABIT_SDK_LOG, "onFailure: " + "UnknownHostException");
            }
            onError(new ApiErrorCodeInfo(URL_INVALID, t.getLocalizedMessage()));
        } else {
            if (getLogControlManager().isLog()) {
                Log.e(PARABIT_SDK_LOG, "onFailure: " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            onError(new ApiErrorCodeInfo(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    t.getLocalizedMessage()));
        }
    }

    public static<T> String getErrorBodyStr(Response<ApiResponse<T>> response) {
        if (response.errorBody() == null) {
            return "";
        }

        String errorBodyStr = "";
        try {
            errorBodyStr = response.errorBody().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return errorBodyStr;
    }

    protected Long getRoundTripTime(Response response) {
        Long roundTripTime = response.raw().sentRequestAtMillis()
                - response.raw().receivedResponseAtMillis();
        return roundTripTime;
    }

//    public abstract void onSuccess(String successMsg, List<T> data);
    public abstract void onApiResponse(String ApiMsg, int httpStatusCode, List<T> data);
    public abstract void onError(ApiErrorCodeInfo apiErrorCodeInfo);

    protected LogControlManager getLogControlManager() {
        return SdkApplicationInstance.getSdkLogControlManager(application);
    }
}
```

The code in the Activity that controls which error is shown

```
  loginViewModel.loginStatusInfo.observe(this, loginStatusInfo -> {
            if (loginStatusInfo.getStatus() == API_SUCCESS_STATUS){
                hideLoadingDialog();
                startHomeActivity();
            }else if (loginStatusInfo.getStatus() == INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) {
                hideLoadingDialog();
                loginErrorDialog(getString(R.string.fail_to_login_server_error));
            }else if(loginStatusInfo.getStatus() == NO_NETWORK_ERROR){<- I added this else if
                hideLoadingDialog();
                loginErrorDialog(getString(R.string.network_require_msg));
            }
            else {
                hideLoadingDialog();
                loginErrorDialog(loginStatusInfo.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually called `ConectivityManager` on the `loginViewModel.loginStatusInfo` method and it worked.

```
   loginViewModel.loginStatusInfo.observe(this, loginStatusInfo -> {
            if (loginStatusInfo.getStatus() == API_SUCCESS_STATUS){
                hideLoadingDialog();
                startHomeActivity();
            }else if (loginStatusInfo.getStatus() == INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) {
                hideLoadingDialog();
                loginErrorDialog(getString(R.string.fail_to_login_server_error));
            }else if(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE == 0){
                hideLoadingDialog();
                networkErrorDialog(getString(R.string.network_require_msg));
            }
            else {
                hideLoadingDialog();
                loginErrorDialog(loginStatusInfo.getMessage());
            }
        });
```